# How to use file strings as commands in c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mkdir

I am trying to make a program on Windows 10 using Visual Studio 2015 that would sim-link certain files to certain locations. I am trying to make a text file with the location of the files, and the sim-link destination to use.

This is an example of the file data that would be in the `properties.txt` file:

> FileLocation: "Z:\Folder\file.txt"
>
> FileMkdirLocation: "Z:\Folder2\file.txt"

I want to use something like `system(mkdir "sim-link_file_location" "file_location")` by changing the data that is in `properties.txt`. I want to be able to add more than 1 file, without recompiling the program and writing each command for each file, one by one.

The problem is that I don't know how to make the commands use the data in the file.

EDIT: I managed to find out a way, but I get errors when compiling the program. I use this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

//initialization of Properties File used
ifstream PropertiesFile ("PropertiesFile.txt");

int main()
{
    //initialization of variables used
    int input_option;
    char FileLocation[256], Command[]="mklink ";
//  string FileLocation, Command;

    PropertiesFile >> FileLocation;

/*  switch (input_option)
    {
    case "add all mods": 
    }
*/

    cout << "FileLocation: " << FileLocation;
    cout << endl;

    strcat(Command, FileLocation);
    Command[strlen(FileLocation)] = '\0';

    cout << Command;
    cout << endl;

    //system(command);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I know that i haven't used all variables yet.
It tells me that "strcat" is deprecated and to use "strcat_s" instead, and when i replace it with that, I get

> "Debug Assertion Failed - Expression: (L"Buffer is too small" && 0)"

Comment: What is your question again?

Comment: i edited it a sec ago. i don't know how to use instead of "sim-link_file_location" the data that is written in the properties.txt file

Comment: Please explain what `sim-link` means - not _symlink_?

Comment: yes. that is simlink

Comment: for heavens sake - use std::string

Comment: did u read the man page for strcat at all? The first param is the destination. https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcat. As they say - if all else fails read the manual

Comment: Why not just use a batch file?

Comment: I'm making it in c++ so I can turn it into a simlink manager, also, to get used to c++ better

Comment: @pm100 I know that's the destination, that's why I'm "pasting" the FileLocation into Command

Comment: Commnd is 8 bytes, you cant just shove stuff into it. use std::string in c++ - please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to make the "Command" char bigger than "FileLocation" because then strcat_s would not be able to copy the content. After that the program worked fine, and there were no other Assert Errors.

Answer (score -2):

The command to create a soft link in linux is: `ln -s <source> <destination>`
You can use this in a `system("");` call, BUT before you continue in your code, you will have to make sure that the kernel finished executing this command.

After that you can read the link as if it was the original file.

Comment: OP is unfortunately using Windows, not Linux.

Comment: And this wouldn't even answer his question if he were using linux.